# Create a property which is not generated in designer

Tags: c#, .net

I use DefaultValue for a property so that it will be not generated in designer when I create a control which has this property in designer. However, with properties which have data type is not standard, example: Image, how to create a default value. Thanks.

This is an example codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DemoChart
{
  public class MyControl : Control
  {
    private Image m_Img = DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link;

    [DefaultValue("DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link")]
    public Image Img
    {
      get { return m_Img; }
      set { m_Img = value; }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Note: DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link is a Image resource which I add in project.

I create a form named Form1, drag a MyControl to this form and it name is myControl1. I open Form1.designer.cs to view generated codes, I still see myControl1's Img property. Why? I use DefaultValue but it doesn't have affect. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Does it call an error? do you get a blank picture?

Comment: Is your `Img` property returns an image?

Comment: When you create `myControl1` then its `Img` property is not set to Default value?

Comment: Do you know the purpose of DefaultValue? I use it to avoid code for this property will be generated in designer when I keep default. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid generating codes for object's property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025592/avoid-generating-codes-for-objects-property)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're assigning a `String` value to the `DefaultValueAttribute` of an `Image` property.
You cannot use `DefaultValueAttribute` this way.

For the designer to work where `DefaultValueAttribute` is not eligible, the alternative approach is tu create two methods: `ResetPropertyName` and `ShouldSerializePropertyName`.
These two methods will be used by the designer in place of the attribute, enabling the **Reset** menu command and avoiding generating unwanted code into **.designer.cs** file

Your code should become something like:

```
private Image m_Img = DefaultImg;
public Image Img
{
  get { return m_Img; }
  set { m_Img = value; }
}

private static readonly Image DefaultImg = DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link;
private void ResetImg() { Img = DefaultImg; }
private bool ShouldSerializeImg() { return (Img != DefaultImg); }
```