# Avoid generating codes for object's property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use DefaultValue for a property so that it will be not generated in designer when I create a control which has this property in designer. However, with properties which have data type is not standard, example: Image, how to use DefaultValue. Thanks.

This is an example codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DemoChart
{
  public class MyControl : Control
  {
    private Image m_Img = DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link;

    [DefaultValue("DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link")]
    public Image Img
    {
      get { return m_Img; }
      set { m_Img = value; }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Note: DemoChart.Properties.Resources.link is a Image resource which I add in project.

I create a form named Form1, drag a MyControl to this form and it name is myControl1. I open Form1.designer.cs to view generated codes, I still see myControl1's Img property. Why? I use DefaultValue but it doesn't have effect. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Please read my question. DefaultValue(true) or DefaultValue(1) -> it is simple but with a Image object, how to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your property has a complex data type then you are supposed to use the [`ShouldSerialize` and `Reset` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).